# How to add Mathematics Subject Classification before keywords in the footnote

Tags: footnotes, amsart

I am using amsart. For keywords they have simply the commnad \keywords .It's necessary to add Mathematics Subject Classification followed by the code before I send my paper in the journal. I am posting my preamble below.

I want it look something like this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{epic}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage
[left=2.7cm,
right=3.0cm,
top=3.5cm,
bottom=4.0cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\def\numset#1{{\\mathbb #1}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{Th}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{Lemma}[Th]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Cor}[Th]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Prop}[Th]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Def}[Th]{Definition}
\newtheorem{Conj}[Th]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{Rem}[Th]{Remark}
\newtheorem{?}[Th]{Problem}
\newtheorem{Ex}[Th]{Example}

\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}
\newcommand{\Hom}{{\rm{Hom}}}
\newcommand{\diam}{{\rm{diam}}}
\newcommand{\ovl}{\overline}
%\newcommand{\M}{\mathbb{M}}


\begin{document}

\title{dddfdgs}

\author{sds Ssdasgh}
\author{Basdishth}




\address{se \\ University of dsdsDshid
\email{dssdasdsogy@gmail.com}
\address{Univsasa\\ Deparsastics}
\email{sadr@gmail.com}


\begin{abstract} lipsum
\end{abstract}
```

\keywords{fdgfg}

```
\maketitle


\section{Introduction} blablbalab

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `amsart` class supports the `\subjclass` command **precisely** for including the MSC code.

Just type in around where you type in the keywords

```
\subjclass[2000]{53C50, 57R25}
```

(though probably at this point you should be using the 2010 MSC codes, in which case, look up the correct codes on the AMS website and replace '2000' by '2010' in the line above.)

Comment: can i replace by $2020$ ? Also how to add $key-words$ ?

Comment: Replacing \subclass[2000]   by \subclass[2020] produces 1991 classification

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR: what version of the AMS document class are you running? The current release, which is version `2.20.6 2020-05-29`, supports 2020 MSC codes (in fact it defaults to the 2020 version). But if you have an older version of the package, it may not.

Comment: For keywords use `\keywords`; this is the same for most document classes.